# Active or passive voice - which to use?

Tags: present-perfect, future, passive-voice, active-voice, future-perfect

In my software, if for some reason the installation fails, I want to display a message.

Which of these is correct?

> Some problem occurred. The installation cannot **proceed**.
>
> Some problem occurred. The installation cannot **be proceeded**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, I have never seen "be proceeded" before. Every time I can remember seeing "proceeded" it has been followed by "to" and a phrase (eg: "proceeded to pick his teeth"). So without an attached phrase it doesn't look like proper English to me. If you want it passive, you need to pick another verb phrase (eg: "be carried out").

Also, I would change the first sentence to either "has occurred", or "*A* problem". What you have works semanticly, but is typically used when one doesn't really care what exactly the specific problem is. While that may be the case, implying your program doesn't care about the error seems kind of user-hostile to me. :-)

In general, many people do feel like it is better to use passive voice on computer errors. You are in a situation where the machine (which is supposed to be serving the user) is refusing to do what was asked. In a human situation this would be considered extreme insubordination. So to cushion the blow, it should be as deferential as possible. Of course there are others who say the flowery language required to accomplish that can obfuscate the nature of the error, which confuses the user. For example, in this particular situation I'd be kind of frustrated that the computer isn't telling me exactly *what* error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct, "The installation cannot proceed". That uses the correct tense. The second is not grammatically correct as written in your question, but can be made correct by adding 'with': "The installation cannot be proceeded with". The 'with' is required in this construct.

I would use the first, "The installation cannot proceed". It is terse, more immediate, and conveys the necessary information in the shortest number of words.

Comment: and @Chris.. As you suggested, i'll go with the second one

Comment: OK. I did suggest going with the first one, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct, but I think you should go for something like:

> **A** problem **has** occurred. The installation cannot proceed.

This sounds more natural. You could optionally insert an "and":

> A problem has occured and the installation cannot proceed.